# How to solve the problem RCVD_BY_IP "Received by mail server with no name"

Tags: email, spam, spamassassin

I'm using MailingCheck to calculate the spam score of my e-mail messages.

There is one problem bugging me that i don't know how to solve.

RCVD_BY_IP "Received by mail server with no name"

It probably has something to do with the mail server i'm using, 
but i don't know which settings to change to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MailingCheck use old version the SpamAssassin. SpamAssassin RCVD_BY_IP rule has been [removed](https://issues.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=4516).

I download Mail-SpamAssassin-3.0.6 source code and find the rule:

```
header RCVD_BY_IP       Received =~ /\bby\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?<!127\.0\.0\.1)\b/
```

Your mail contain "Received: by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" header. It's normal. MailingCheck not updated SpamAssassin.